# JBPM JAXB api marshalling

Tags: jbpm

I have 2 problems with jbpm jaxb, first:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "clientInfo". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
```

I how do i stop jbpm from loading those classes to jaxb context. I cant change XML. I dont need them there, jbpm is loading all Jaxb classes with jaxb annotations can i exclude jar or package?

second problem:

```
org.jbpm.process.instance.command.UpdateProcessCommand does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.jbpm.process.instance.command.UpdateProcessCommand
```

i have no idea why this problem shows up

version JBPM 7.3

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the newest non-SNAPSHOT version of jbpm? The issue might be with the jbpm itself.